# How to exclude folders when using Directory.GetDirectories

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, getdirectories

I want to return a list of all the subdirectories in the 'SomeFolder' directory **excluding** the 'Admin' and 'Templates' directories.

I have the following folder structure (simplified):

```
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\SomeFolder\RandomString
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\SomeFolder\RandomString
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\SomeFolder\RandomString
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\SomeFolder\Admin 
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\SomeFolder\Templates
```

'SomeFolder' can contain a varying number a 'RandomString' folders (anywhere from ~10 to ~100).

Here is what I have tried:

```
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(Server.MapPath(".."))
    .Where(s => !s.EndsWith("Admin") || !s.EndsWith("Templates"));
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        lit.Text += Environment.NewLine + dir;
    }
```

This returns the full list of folders (shown above) without 'Admin' and 'Templates' filtered out.

Interestingly, if I change the LINQ `.Where` clause to *include*, instead of *exclude*, 'Admin' and 'Templates' it works, meaning it returns just the paths for 'Admin' and 'Templates'.

```
.Where(s => s.EndsWith("Admin") || s.EndsWith("Templates"));
```

If LINQ is not the solution, is there any way to use the GetDirectories SearchPattern to filter out directories?

Comment: `.Where(it => !ExcludedFolders.Any(it.Contains));`
and 
`private IEnumerable<string> ExcludedFolders { get; } = new[] { "Admin", "Templates" };`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the opposite of (A || B) is (!A && !B), so in your code it should be &&, not ||...

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks.  What a rookie mistake.  I had even had a (obviously too quick) look at the C# operators reference to make sure I should have using the conditional and not the logical.  Will accept when the 10 min window is up.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like:

```
//list your excluded dirs
private List<string> _excludedDirectories= new List<string>() { "Admin", "Templates" };

//method to check
static bool isExcluded(List<string> exludedDirList, string target)
{
    return exludedDirList.Any(d => new DirectoryInfo(target).Name.Equals(d));
}

//then use this
var filteredDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(d => !isExcluded(_excludedDirectories, d));
```

Comment: wow surprisingly, when i searched this, i found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003440/c-sharp-directory-getdirectories-excluding-folders). very similar to mine.

Comment: This is a nice clean solution.  I am doing a entire server. Do you think the performance will be better if I don't use DirectoryInfo and use string manipulation.  IE tagert.EndWith(d)

Comment: @H20rider, significant performance boost? no. I don't think so.

Comment: best answer, definitely!

The chosen answer is working for this example, but this solution is clean and easy to maintain if you need to add folders / remove folders without making a huge && || && concat